# How do I change the text of OK buttons in the Sitecore Content Editor?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

This particular project has been inherited from another vendor.  I have never modified the language on the backend before.  Anyone out there done this before?

[image: Sitecore Oklahoma Button]

Notice the "Oklahoma" button

Comment: Looks like someone had a little too much fun with find & replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log into the Sitecore desktop and change to the **Core** database. Open this path:

/sitecore/system/Dictionary/O/OK

Change the **Phrase** field to change the text on your OK button.

[image: Change the Phrase field to change the OK button text]

Comment: Whew, this seemed to fix it!  I wonder if this may have been originally caused by some Dictionary items in the Master DB.  There are a list of states with Oklahoma listed.  As soon as I switched to Core and put "OK" in the phrase field as shown in your answer it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that someone probably put a duplicate "OK" key in there - presumably as a translation for the "OK = Oklahoma" state translation.

Answer (score 2):

`<Literal Text='${StringUtil.GetString($OKButton, "OK")}'/>` in `\sitecore\shell\Controls\Dialogs\FormDialog.xml`

Check if the default "OK" has been changed.

Comment: I see the line you've described.  It does not appear to be modified, however I can probably follow that StringUtil class to see what's up.  Thanks, I will update when I find this bugger. :D

Comment: Is it just this single dialog which the OK button has been modified in? The OKButton var may be set in `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs\LayoutDetails\LayoutDetails.xml`, check in there too. GetString doesn't do anything too clever, just checks whether first param has value else return default.

Comment: Guessing you did a content search of the files for the string "Oklahoma"? I use [GrepWin](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html)

Comment: Yes, looked all over.  Turned out to be the Dictionary item in the Core database as mentioned by @Richard Seal.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: Great. I assumed it was a dictionary value but wasn't sure where they were set. Good to know.